# reputation stopped incrementing

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I noticed in the last few hours that my reputation has stopped incrementing when I get new up-votes: -

[image]

Has something gone wrong or has the well dried up?

Comment: You are on the dotted-border watch list, so we get to arbitrarily mess with your stats for fun. I think the official cover story is something about a rep cap, LOL! I think they're also not going to send you the T shirt when you get to 5000 rep, and I forget what else they do to the dotted-border dweebs.

Comment: @OlinLathrop That is sooooooo cruel and I was relying on that T shirt to supplement my depleted wardrobe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the FAQ:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

> ... You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that
>   votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any
>   reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject
>   to the daily reputation limit.

This means that (assuming you don't have any questions upvoted) you can receive 20 answer upvotes in a day before the reputation cap kicks in for that day. Other sources of reputation, such as an answer being accepted, or receiving a bounty, do *not* count towards your 200 reputation limit.

Below is a picture of your reputation for April 5th, when you received 230 reputation. You can see each row labeled **upvote** adds up to a total of 200 reputation, which is exactly the reputation cap. You didn't "lose" any reputation due to having more than 20 upvotes. You also had two answers accepted as "correct". These are shown as "+15" and are outlined in green. The "accept" reward does not count towards your 200 reputation limit, nor does reaching the 200 reputation limit prevent you from receiving that 30 reputation.

[image: April 5th Reputation]

On May 3rd, you received reputation only from upvotes (no "accepts"). You can see that the first 200 reputation was counted, and the other upvotes are acknowledged but not counted. You can still gain reputation, but it can only be from answers accepting, or bounties, not upvotes.

[image: May 3rd Reputation]

Comment: Many thanks - told you i could be thick!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a daily cap on reputation increase.

Comment: Thanks for the info but when did that start? I ask because I remember getting over 200 recently (maybe a month ago)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I don't pay attention to rep.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: Basically, there is a 200 rep cap from question and answer upvotes. Answer accepts (+15) and bounties are not affected by this cap.

Comment: @W5VO - on April 5th this year i received a daily reputation increase of 230 - how does this work when the daily cap is supposedly 200?

Comment: @Andyaka Again, you have exactly 200 reputation from upvotes, and two accepts (+30).

Comment: @W5VO I know I must be being thick but I don't get what you say. This is purely based on me getting 230 on April 5th. If you'd do me the honour of spelling it out for me I'd appreciate it.... or just ignore me till I figure it myself. Your time is as precious as everyones!!